# Vertically aligning content across two different (parallel) columns using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

I'm using CSS grid layout, and would like to vertically align images in the left column to associated text in the right column.  Is there a way to do that using CSS (without JavaScript)?

There are many posts about aligning content *in the same column*, which is not what I need.  I need to align it across *two different columns*.

Example:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="left-col">
<img src="1.png" class="p1"/>
<img src="2.png" class="p2"/>
<img src="3.png" class="p2"/>
</div>
<div class="right-col">
<p class="p1">Lorem ipsum...</p>
<p class="p2">Lorem ipsum...</p>
<p class="p3">Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to align each `img.pN` with the corresponding `p.pN`.

I'm using vanilla HTML and CSS, not Bootstrap.  I'd rather avoid Javascript but can use it if necessary.  I can't use any external libraries beyond that, though.

---

As requested, here is the column CSS:

I started with a simple grid CSS, but can switch to anything which gives me the desired result:

```
div.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

If a `flex` layout would be better, I'm open to that.

Comment: Can you include your grid css?

Comment: @mykaf Done (updated).

Comment: You currently only have one grid row, and the items in each column don't know about the items in the other column. I would define three grid rows.

Comment: Perhaps check out some [use case examples](https://gridbyexample.com/examples/).